# change color of stepper input text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

we are using the stepper built into flutter and we want to change the input text color to white, its black by default: here is the code:

```
 List<Step> steps = [
new Step(
    title: const Text('First Name', style: TextStyle( color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19.0 )),

    isActive: true,

    state: StepState.indexed,
    content: new TextFormField(
      focusNode: _focusNode,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      autocorrect: false,
      onSaved: (String value) {
        data.firstname = value;
      },
      maxLines: 1,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty || value.length < 1) {
          return 'Please enter first name';
        }
      },
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Enter your first name',
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white),
          labelStyle:
              new TextStyle(decorationStyle: TextDecorationStyle.solid,color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0))
              ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code.

```
TextField(
      style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ...
```